# Store table as response into DataFrame using Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have part of code that extracts the source of a specific page and here's sample of the HTML contents

```html
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<style type="text/css">
         th,td{
         text-align: center !important;
         }
         
         </style>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr class="">
<th style="text-align:center;" width="5%">م</th>
<th style="text-align:center;" width="15%">التاريخ</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">العملية</th>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>1</td>
<td dir="ltr">2021-02-02</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">محضراثبات حاله</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>2</td>
<td dir="ltr">2021-02-02</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>3</td>
<td dir="ltr">2021-01-20</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>4</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-09-28</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">امر منع سفر</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>5</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-09-22</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>6</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-09-07</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">امر ضبط واحضار مدين</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>7</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-09-02</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>8</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-03-03</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>9</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-03-01</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طـلب ضبط واحضار مدين</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>10</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-03-01</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طلب حجز و ضبط سيارة</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>11</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-03-01</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>12</td>
<td dir="ltr">2020-03-01</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">طلب منع سفر</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>13</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-10-27</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;">ايصال تحصيل</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>14</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-06-24</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> جلسة المحكمة الكلية - حكم قطعي  </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>15</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-06-10</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> جلسة المحكمة الكلية - قضية محجوزة للحكم  - الجلسة القادمة (24-06-2019)</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>16</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-05-30</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> اعلان بجلسة</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>17</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-05-06</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> جلسة المحكمة الكلية - قرار تأجيل للاعلان  - الجلسة القادمة (10-06-2019)</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowEven" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>18</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-04-23</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> اعلان بجلسة</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center" class="resultRowOdd" style="line-height:25px;">
<td>19</td>
<td dir="ltr">2019-04-14</td>
<td style="padding-right:10px;"> سجلت القضية في دائرة  تجارى كلي في  المحكمة الكلية برقم  5874 سنة  2019</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have used `requests` package and `BeautfiulSoup`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Till this point everything is OK. What I am trying to do now is to convert the table in the response to DataFrame using Pandas .. Can you please help me with that?

I have by chance found something that solved the proble

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
```

so using `read_html` is a great feature in pandas.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

```
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)

print(df[0])
```

Output

```
     م     التاريخ                                            العملية
0    1  2021-02-02                                     محضراثبات حاله
1    2  2021-02-02                 محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير
2    3  2021-01-20                         طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير
3    4  2020-09-28                                        امر منع سفر
4    5  2020-09-22                 محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير
5    6  2020-09-07                                امر ضبط واحضار مدين
6    7  2020-09-02                 محضرحجزتنفيذى بما للمدين لدى الغير
7    8  2020-03-03                         طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير
8    9  2020-03-01                               طـلب ضبط واحضار مدين
9   10  2020-03-01                                طلب حجز و ضبط سيارة
10  11  2020-03-01                         طلب حجزما للمدين لدى الغير
11  12  2020-03-01                                        طلب منع سفر
12  13  2019-10-27                                        ايصال تحصيل
13  14  2019-06-24                     جلسة المحكمة الكلية - حكم قطعي
14  15  2019-06-10  جلسة المحكمة الكلية - قضية محجوزة للحكم - الجل...
15  16  2019-05-30                                        اعلان بجلسة
16  17  2019-05-06  جلسة المحكمة الكلية - قرار تأجيل للاعلان - الج...
17  18  2019-04-23                                        اعلان بجلسة
18  19  2019-04-14  سجلت القضية في دائرة تجارى كلي في المحكمة الكل...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already posted the same trick at the end of the question. Thank you very much for your great support.
Can you tell me how did you read the local HTML ?

Comment: Saw that just now. Seems that you have realised on your own. A bit of research before asking a question would help.

Comment: I already searched but after posting the question, I found it by chance from some comments.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you read the local HTML ?

Comment: No issues. Glad that you found it on your own. I'll leave it here for other people who face this.

Comment: Just initialized a multiline string

Comment: Can you show me that as I am a newbie to such stuff?

Comment: `s = """<html></html>"""`